# Google Closure - Cropping Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-closure

Is there a way to crop or trim an image files by using Google Closure?

If any, what module or package do I have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Closure Library includes a [graphics](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fclosure%2Fgoog%2Fgraphics) package, but it does not come with built-in support for image cropping or trimming, other than the standard HTML5 canvas functionality accessible via the canvas wrappers.

For examples, see the [demos under **Graphics**](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/index.html).